# if else dividing in BASH

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am doing a school assignment in bash and got this code:

```
if a < 0
    a = a/b
else
    a = b/a
fi
```

The assignment says that we need to divide two number read from the keyboard, and check if the first number is larger than the number 0.

```
echo "Write two numbers, with a space, that need to be divided:"
read a b
  if a > 0
    a = $a / $b
  else
    a = $b / $a
fi

echo "$a"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces around `=`, otherwise bash will try to execute `a`.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught a lot of these issues automatically

Comment: Do you really have to use `bash` in a school assignment? It would be much easier to implement this in `perl` or `python`.

Comment: @VrataBlazek, ...I'd suggest `awk` as an ideal choice, as it's part of POSIX (which neither perl nor python is) and has floating-point math support. Starting someone on a path to perl seems a lot like recruiting for the Dark Side. :)

Comment: @VrataBlazek, ...that said, I'm not sure about "easier" -- within the integer-math boundaries of the language, the relevant bash syntax isn't exactly hard to use.

Comment: ...to explain the initial behavior, `a < 0` is running a command named `a` with its input from a file named `0`, just like `cat < in.txt` is running a command named `cat` with its input from `in.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a math context in bash uses `(( ))`. Note that bash only supports integer math natively -- be sure you aren't expecting fractional output (or using fractional inputs), and see [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) if this limitation is relevant to you.

```
if (( a > 0 )); then
  a=$(( a / b ))
else
  a=$(( b / a ))
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Charles Duffy, that worked. :)